# Column filter(eg. column name = X) vs row filter performance in HBase?

Tags: hbase

For example, I have data in hbase like this;

```
ROW             COLUMN
id-time         cf:s1, cf:s2, cf:s3, cf:s4, cf:s5
id-time1        cf:s1, cf:s2, cf:s3, cf:s4, cf:s5
id-time2        cf:s1, cf:s2, cf:s3, cf:s4, cf:s5
id-time3        cf:s1, cf:s2, cf:s3, cf:s4, cf:s5
```

I want to get **cf:s3** values based on rowKey(time range scan. Eg time-time3).

Also, another option,

```
ROW             COLUMN
id-time-s1      cf:val
id-time1-s2     cf:val
id-time1-s3     cf:val
id-time2-s3     cf:val
id-time2-s4     cf:val
id-time3-s4     cf:val
id-time3-s5     cf:val
```

Like above, I want to get **s3** values based on rowKey(time range query).

**Which one is better on read performance?**

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you have to do a **full scan** with a column filter (you need to read s3 from each row) while in the second case you can do a **partial scan** (you can define a *start row key - end row key* interval) with a column family filter. A partial scan will always be more efficient then a full one, especially as your table grows.

Comment: For example; I want to get data between time-time2. In the first case, Partially scan will be before. Then column filters will applied? Right? In the second case, partially scan will be get data directly without any column filter. Thus, read query performance will be greater than the first case.

Comment: The row filter will alway be applied first. If you filter by row key you do a partial scan which will be applied first, the scan is intended by row. A column/column family filter will be applied later.

Comment: So, for example one row1 has s1, s2, s3, s4 column in cf. row2 has s55, s22, s45, s49 column in cf. All other rows has different columns  in the same column family than others rows. Will it effect read performance?

Comment: Well, if only one row has the value you need (let's say s3) you can get that row with a direct get by key operation, which is way faster than a scan (even a partial one).

Comment: In fact, I know that each row has different column in the same column family, thus column family will be have a lot of different columns. But each row will have about 10 columns. In the HBase backend, when I want to scan by row key time range scan, does a lot of columns  effects performance?

Comment: Getting a lot of columns from a few rows (considering simple columns with standard values, if each column contains a serialized avro or something like that you have to do some test) is less time consuming then getting a few columns from a lot of rows.

Comment: Well, row1 has s1, s2, s3, s4 columns,  row2 has s31, s32, s33, s34 column,  row3 has s41, s42, s43, s44 columns. Each row has time-dependent changes. For example, row1time1-row1time2... I want to get s3 of row1 using time range query, firstly, partial scan will be applied.Then columns filter will be applied. But Will column filter applied to other columns? for example; s43, s44, s31, s32.. Because row1 don't have these columns.

Comment: Keep in mind that the column filter works on the column qualifier name, so if that qualifier it's not present nothing will be returned for that row. You can also name your columns with a meaningful prefix and use a column prefix filter to catch a group of them.

Comment: Thank you so much!